Angular not subscribing to SignalR message from net core webApi
i have an app with asp net core web api and angular ,
i want response of payment bank gateway (that receive from their api),from my own web api to angular ,
my server side code is :

`
[HttpPost("payment-call-back")]
public async Task PaymentCallBack([FromQuery] string pspName, [FromQuery] string us, [FromForm] PaymentCallBack param)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
var result = await _paymentService.PaymentCallBack(pspName, us, param);
{result.Data}";

     if (result.Status == DomainClass.Enum.StatusEnum.Success)
     {        
         await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", result.Data);
         return Ok("ok");          
     }
     else
         return JsonResponseStatus.Result(result);
 }
 return JsonResponseStatus.BadRequest();

}
`
and client side is :

`
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {
private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
private paymentStatusSubject: Subject = new Subject();

@Output() onSignalRMessage: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
constructor(private router: Router) {
this.startConnection();
this.receiveMessage();
}
public startConnection = () => {
console.log('Starting connection...');
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl('http://localhost:5033/myHub')
  .build();

this.hubConnection.start()
  .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));

}
receiveMessage = () => {
this.hubConnection.on('SendMessageToClient', (message: string) => {
  console.log('receiveMessage: ' + message);

  this.paymentStatusSubject.next(message);
  this.onSignalRMessage.emit(this.paymentStatusSubject);

});

}
}
`
and in app.component.ts :
 public messages = [];

ngOnInit() {
this.signalRService.onSignalRMessage.subscribe((data) => {
  
    this.messages.push(data);
     console.log('receiveMessage: ' + this.messages[0]);
  })
}

but instead of running angular , it redirect to my webapi Uri (http://localhost:5033/Account/payment-call-back?pspName=Newsamanpay&us=ecf12cf0-26c4-4497-c4cf-08dbca5fd598) and show ok !!!
can any one help me ??
